# Background image scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have that code for my background:

```
    body{

       background:url(pics/bg.jpg)no-repeat center center;background-size:cover;}

                   }
```

The problem is that when I scroll the page down the image scrolls and I don't want it:Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't used background-attachment:fixed.
There are 2 ways to do it:

```
 body{background:url(pics/bg.png)no-repeat center center fixed;}
```

or

```
 body{background:url(pics/bg.png)no-repeat center center;
background-attachment:fixed;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add background-attachment: fixed; and delete one } like this:

```
body {
   background:url(pics/bg.jpg)no-repeat center center;
   background-size:cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `background-attachment: fixed`.